# How to make transistor work like a switch controlled by a PWM signal

Tags: transistors, switches, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply

So, I need a switch that opens when a pwm signal is high(5V) and then when the pwm signal is low(0V) it has to close. I need this to switched power supply. I know that a transistor can be used to this application. Switching its polarity i can have my switch, but I'm not being able to do this. Can you guys some some examples or some electrical diagrams?

Thanks,

Comment: perhaps a PNP transistor ?  MOSFET seems obvious better choice though..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transistor as a switch and there are plenty of resources describing that, my favorite is [Electronics Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html).

Using a transistor with PWM though is a completely different story: you need a very fast transistor with very low capacitance and pretty robust voltage source, capable to cope with continous current spikes.

A MOSFET CONTINOUS be a better choice, as it operates on voltage rather than current, but once again you need a pretty fast MOSFET with low capacitance.

Obviously this also depends on your PWM frequency, but a transistor with PWM is something pretty strange: I wonder what circuit would require such solution...